# After Effects Aerender and JSON sourceData

Tags: javascript, json, render, after-effects

I have a problem...
I can write a JSON file with the information that i need and i can make these informations show up on placeholders.
Everything is wonderful til then.
BUT, when i try render by cmd using Aerender process, the texts imported from JSON file doesnt appears, but, when i try to render using AE program normally, it works properly. I dont have any idea why its happening.
The JS script that i using to import the data from JSON file is:

```
var content = footage('content.JSON').sourceData;
content[0].title;
```

[Json Working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PR1v.png)

When i save the project and try render using cmd aerender, the json data disappears.

Answer (score 0):

### SIMPLE ANSWER

Add your **json file as a layer** in your comp and point your text expression to your json layer.

[checkout this exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfBOe.png)

---

### HOW TO:

In this example, our json footage was called "data.json".

So, create a comp and add a text.

#### 1 Import and place your data.json footage to your comp.

check if Data > Text > Expression of this layer is like this

```
footage("data.json").dataValue([0])
```

#### 2 Open expression panel of your text and add this code

```
thisComp.layer("data.json")("Data")("Outline")("text")
```

Notice that text layer expression is pointing to our json layer NOT direct to our json footage.

*Hope that it helps!*